# How do I render square ListItem avatar instead of round?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I need to render square avatar. How do I do it?

I have implemented the listItem code as provided by react native element document: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html

It works well but in this version of react native element 1.1.0 I don't know how to render square avatar instead of round.

```
 <ListItem
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={item.subtitle}
        leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.icon } }}
    />
```

I need to have left squar avatar filling the listview height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `rounded` prop as `false`

with props:

```
<ListItem
    title={item.name}
    subtitle={item.subtitle}
    leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.icon }, rounded: false}}
/>
```

or with component:

```
<ListItem
    title={item.name}
    subtitle={item.subtitle}
    leftAvatar={<Avatar source={{uri: item.icon}} rounded={false} /> }
/>
```

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/avatar.html#avatar-props